# Line Intersections tool missing from QGIS 2.16

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.16

In QGIS 2.14 the Line Intersections tool was under Vector->Analysis. I can't find it in 2.16 and it doesn't appear to have been integrated as an option in the normal intersection tool. Google hasn't been helpful. Does anyone know where it's been moved too? Related question, does QGIS have a tool search function the same way esri does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enable the Processing Toolbox via the menu or with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> key combination. This is the new world of QGIS algorithms and it has a nice search feature. I see "Line intersections" in 2.16.